# Sum up till date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to summarize the data with total sums till the min date selected in the slicer with one more condition. But somehow it does not sum up. what am i missing ?

```
Till Date Sum =
VAR _lastdate =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] ) ) - 1
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            'Mizan Full'[Firma Adı],
            'Mizan Full'[Hesap No],
            'Mizan Full'[Hesap Grup Adı],
            "Önceki Toplam", SUM ( 'Mizan Full'[Rapor USD] )
        ),
        'Mizan Full'[Hesap Grubu] = "100",
        'Mizan Full'[Tarih] <= _lastdate
    )
```

Edit : The problem is with the _lastdate, it calculates normally separately but when in the formula, it gets the minimum date of all data, not the selected one.

I also tried with the FILTER() as below, still not returns correct result.

```
Till Date Sum =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Mizan Full'[Firma Adı],
    'Mizan Full'[Hesap No],
    'Mizan Full'[Hesap Grup Adı],
    FILTER ( 'Mizan Full', 'Mizan Full'[Hesap Grubu] = "100" ),
    FILTER (
        'Mizan Full',
        'Mizan Full'[Tarih]
            <= CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] ) ) - 1
    ),
    "Önceki Toplam", SUM ( 'Mizan Full'[Rapor USD] )
)
```

Comment: did you try without ALLSELECTED ()? Check this  with replacing to ALL(). If result is the same, then you just removed any context for the date column

Comment: @Mik welcome back ))) i tried without ALLSELECTED and also with ALL , still no result...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

VERSION-1

```
Till Date Sum =
VAR _lastdate =
    CALCULATE(MINX ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] ), 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] ))
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                'Mizan Full',
                'Mizan Full'[Firma Adı],
                'Mizan Full'[Hesap No],
                'Mizan Full'[Hesap Grup Adı]
            ),
            "Önceki Toplam", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Mizan Full'[Rapor USD] ) )
        ),
        'Mizan Full'[Hesap Grubu] = "100",
        'Mizan Full'[Tarih] <= _lastdate
    )
```

VERSION-2

```
Till Date Sum =
VAR _lastdate =
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] ),
        MINX ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] ), 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] )
            = MIN ( 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                'Mizan Full',
                'Mizan Full'[Firma Adı],
                'Mizan Full'[Hesap No],
                'Mizan Full'[Hesap Grup Adı]
            ),
            "Önceki Toplam", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Mizan Full'[Rapor USD] ) )
        ),
        'Mizan Full'[Hesap Grubu] = "100",
        'Mizan Full'[Tarih] <= _lastdate
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @Ozan Sen this is a measure, i was trying to create a separated/summarized table which I believe to calculate faster...

Comment: If you want to create a summary table, your code looks fine. What error It returns ? By the way, how do you know that summarized table calculate faster without testing it? It is not always the case unfortunately.

Comment: no errors and it doesnt calculate as supposed to be. when i test the _lastdate with ">" it calculates normally. I believe it gets the minimum date of all data, not the selected date in the slicer.

Comment: and I cannot insert the _lastdate formula directly into the calculatedtable formula, it doesnt like it there )))

Comment: I tried that already, same result... (((

Comment: Okay. I will share some code soon with some changes.

Comment: I updated it. Can you please test it , and let me know please.

Comment: MIX() also didnt get the expected date... When I manually write a 'Mizan Full'[Tarih] <= date(2022,3,31) for example, it calculates normally.

Comment: Good to solve problems using static codes; but inefficient. What if you put calculate before MINX()... I updated it. Still doesn't take the right date ?

Comment: i used static to check the code except the date part only. calculate minx also didnt work (((

Comment: I understand. I changed the structure of "VAR _lastdate", and updated it as VERSION-2. I used SELECTEDVALUE() with filter argument. Could you please test it ?

Comment: sorry but didnt work. I used **FIRSTDATE('Mizan Full'[Tarih])** in the label but it also didnt work in this calculation ‍♂️

Comment: Oh my god! I made one more update in VERSION-2. I hope It solves this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247280/discussion-between-umut-k-and-ozan-sen).